# How to change/remove form border color on selection?(Chrome)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, webkit

So I'm using

```
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
```

for a text entry field right now, but the problem is that once the field is `selected`, there is a `border` without the `border radius` modified.

So my question is does anyone know how to modify this?

Comment: I was basically looking for the webkit equivalent to -moz-outline-radius but after searching for a while I think that it isn't supported.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can set the outline to have a radius like the border but you can remove it with

```
outline:none;
```

Comment: Ah outline, that's the word I'm looking for. Gonna search and see if I find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the outline you may also use

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

Answer (score 0):

No webkit equivalent to -moz-outline-radius at the moment

Answer (score 0):

While there's no (so far as I'm aware) cross-browser implementation of `outline-radius`, or even a vendor-prefixed implementation other than the `-moz-` variant, you could perhaps *emulate* it with an inset `box-shadow`:

```
.elementClass {
    padding: 0.2em;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid #000; /* in Chromium 18/Ubuntu 11.04 setting
                               the border is required for the outline
                               to be applied, this may not be true elsewhere */
    border-radius: 0.4em;
}

.elementClass:focus,
.elementClass:active {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 2px #f90;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/DW7q3/).